# problema formato numeros csharp

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema a la hora de convertir los numero en millar, no me los convierte, donde podria estar el problema?
este es mi codigo:

```
string canjeados1 = dobj1["useCount"].ToString();

NumCanjeados.Text = string.Format("{0,10:0.0}", canjeados1);
```

En cambio si añado los numeros manualmente si funcniona ejemplo:

```
NumCanjeados.Text = string.Format("{0,10:0.0}", 5000);
```

< Este si me lo convierte

Comment: `canjeados1` es un string y `5000` es un int, puedes usar `Convert.ToInt32(canjeados)` para que funcione

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba convirtiendo tu valor `string` en un valor numérico, para así poder hacer buen uso del `string.Format()`.

```
string canjeados1 = dobj1["useCount"].ToString();
NumCanjeados.Text = string.Format("{0,10:0.0}", Convert.ToInt32(canjeados1));
```

Adicional te dejo información con ejemplos de como dar un formato correcto.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya esta solucionado